# How to order attributes by suffix in FME?

Tags: fme-form, sorting

I have a table with attributes containing a suffix of the form `_DIGIT`. FME displays the table like this:

| country | name_0 | name_1 | name_2 | platforms_0 | platforms_1 | platforms_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Netherlands | Utrecht Centraal | Amsterdam Centraal |  | 16 | 11 |  |
| France | Gare du Nord |  |  | 32 |  |  |
| Germany | Hamburg Hbf | Munich Hbf | Frankfurt(Main) Hbf | 12 | 32 | 29 |

But I need it ordered like this:

| country | name_0 | platforms_0 | name_1 | platforms_1 | name_2 | platforms_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Netherlands | Utrecht Centraal | 16 | Amsterdam Centraal | 11 |  |  |
| France | Gare du Nord | 32 |  |  |  |  |
| Germany | Hamburg Hbf | 12 | Munich Hbf | 32 | Frankfurt(Main) Hbf | 29 |

Where the attributes are ordered by their suffix `_DIGIT` and the ones not containing the `_` suffix in front.
Using the `AttributeManager` is no option since the length of the suffix sequence can range up to 106 items and is variable every time I run the workspace. The `Sorter` only sorts the features inside the attributes, but not the attributes themselves. Perhaps a schema could help, but I have no clue how to work with those.

I'm using FME Workbench 2021.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to fix the order in the output file, not in workbench.

- Use an AttributeCreator to set a Schema Definition Name. (For example, fme_feature_type_name = StationsByCountry)
- Use a SchemaScanner to get a Schema Feature. Select fme_feature_type_name as Schema Definition Name, set attributes to ignore to "fme_" which will prevent the FME technical attributes contaminate your output.
- Use a ListSorter on the Schema Feature, sort on attribute{}.name.
- Connect the Schema Feature and the Data Features to a Sorter to make sure the Schema Feature is the first one.
- Connect the Sorter outputport to the FeatureWriter inputport.
- In the FeatureWriter, check the Dynamic Schema Definition checkbox, set Feature Type Name to fme_feature_type_name.
- In the tab User Attributes, remove all attributes.
- Run workbench.

[image: sample workspace]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still a bit puzzled by how it works. Where do the 'real' features come in? all the way to the end where the FeatureWriter has an outputport?

Comment: The real features go into the SchemaScanner, out from the Outputport of the SchemaScanner, via the sorter into the FeatureWriter. The first 2 transformers are used to create dummy data, these you replace with your data.

Comment: Did you get this to work or do you need any more help? If you ask this question on the safe forum I can provide a working sample.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, the attributes are not sorted on suffix

Comment: It worked for me using your data sample. Once you have the Schema Feature, you can explode the list to features, sort as you want and rebuild the list in the order you need.